# Is it possible to programmatically cancel/stop a started download from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Our application implements a custom download manager.

So actually this means that when a user starts a download of a resource he/she has the opportunity to cancel it through a UI button from the app, which actually sends some event to the server to cancel the downloading (the connection is disconnected and etc).

But since recently Chrome added auto-resume of failed downloads, so the same request is resumed to be downloaded again from the Chrome Download Manager, it's because Chrome cannot distinguish that the user/server intentionally canceled the HTTP connection so it revokes it again.

Currently, we download resources using IFrame, but once the download is started by the browser changing the IFrame's src attribute is not relevant anymore. I've tried to use `<a href='...' download>` but the issue is the same.

Maybe there's some API at least for Chrome? (There's actually such for Chrome extensions but this is not  the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the downloads that are managed by the download manager, of the browser.

If you want to control the download then you need to fetch the file JavaScript by e.g. utilizing the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API).

After you downloaded the Data you can pass that file to the download manager of the browser.

Each of those tasks can be solved in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like add a unique key to the URL for each download request? When the user cancels the download, you invalidate the key so that the URL cannot be used again to download that resource - and in the process prevents Chrome from being able to resume the download.

Comment: Yes, something like this could work but requires some changes in the server code. Unfortunately I think @t.niese 's anwser is  the right one